# Rails Backend For Streaming Android Videos

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am currently building an app that will allow users to upload videos and view other users videos in a stream. Sort of like Vine. I have been using rails for over a year now but I am not sure how to go about implementing the backend for the android application.

My understanding of the situation is that I must use a json call to my rails api that will upload the video file to Amazon s3 or CloudFront. I then need to make the Amazon video file or url be stored or linked to a URL that the Rails app creates for the user.

After that, I would need to play the video (and other people's videos) back to the android application.

It looks like there are a lot of pitfalls to this. If anyone knows the correct way to go about doing this, I would be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What are the pitfalls you are looking to avoid?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I just know it's complicated doing video streaming to android and I don't want to spend months going in one direction only to find out it's not compatible with it.

Comment: I'm thinking that the first thing I should do is make an android application that uploads a video and a rails app that accepts that video and downloads it to Amazon. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: On SO, you need to try something first. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably want to use a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Should host your videos on a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Can use [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) to stream some types of videos on Android.